# Position checkbox dynamically inside linear layout android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-checkbox

I want to have an image view and a checkbox right below it. I have been able to get something close. But, my checkbox is not aligned in the center. How do I position the checkbox in the center?
Here's my code:

```
        // Creating a new LinearLayout
         linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);

        // Setting the orientation to vertical
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Defining the LinearLayout layout parameters to wrap content.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        linearLayout.addView(imageView);

        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(mContext);
        checkbox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);//this does not help

        linearLayout.addView(checkbox);
```

Comment: add your screen shot. because checkbox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); will position the text in center.

Comment: try your linearlayout to be in center..LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take out your checkbox from that `LinearLayout` to another `LinearLayout` in your xml file. Or Insert a `RelativeLayout` below your Image View.

Answer (score 0):

Damn! In your case `RelativeLayout` will be more useful than `LinearLayout`.

I achieved using `RelativeLayout`, check below code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);




        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.testing);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(imageparam);
        imageView.setId(1);
        layout.addView(imageView);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams checkparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        checkparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());

        checkparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);


        checkbox.setLayoutParams(checkparam);
        layout.addView(checkbox);
        setContentView(layout,llp);
```